# Can I safely ignore circular dependency warning when used in a decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have two classes defined like this:

```
// src/app/my-mapper.ts
export class MyMapper implements Mapper<MyModel> {
  public mapTo(source: any): MyModel {
    // map stuff...
  }
}
```

and

```
// src/app/my-model.ts
@mappedBy(MyMapper)
export class MyModel {
  // fields etc...
  public someFunction(): void {
    // stuff...
  }
}
```

My code works (I use a `MapperWorker` to map plain JS objects to concrete objects, `MyModel` in this case), I can call `myModel.someFunction();`

However, I get the following warning when compiling:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src/app/my-mapper.ts ->
>   src/app/my-model.ts -> src/app/my-mapper.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src/app/my-model.ts ->
>   src/app/my-mapper.ts -> src/app/my-model.ts

I don't know if my code is problematic or if this warning can safely be ignored, if it is safe to ignore then what's the best way of suppressing it?

I'm not sure if the error is generated by the Typescript compiler or Angular CLI. Moving the classes to the same file (with the mapper first) gets rid of the warning, but I don't want to have to do that.

Comment: You could import from a third file, depends on all your imports. See the "logic" in https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-circular-dependencies

Comment: @sebilasse I'm not sure I entirely follow your point "You could import from a third file" are you able to elaborate?

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. The code itself is workable, isn't it? Since MyModel is used only as type in my-mapper.ts, this shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: @Neilos See the Readme "Inside the rules" : For example the "imports-after-export" rule : Consider `MyMapper` as "A" and `MyModel` as "B" (?)

Comment: btw: estus is basically right - but my goal would also be 0% warnings ;) @Neilos - please feel free to comment on https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2017/11/01/common-typescript-error-messages/

Comment: @estus yes it would seem that these warnings are erroneous and that there is no error but as sebilasse says getting a warning free compilation would be preferred. Other than placing the two classes in the same file I am unable to make the warning go away, which might not actually be such a bad idea as the two classes are intrinsically linked, I'll play about with it until I find a working solution that I am happy with.

Comment: Create IMyModel interface that reflects your expectations from MyModel. Then you can do `MyModel implements IMyModel` and use IMyModel instead of MyModel when using it as a type. I'm not sure if the compiler still complains if IMyModel resides in same my-model.ts, but you can move it to another file if this is the case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't the "imports-after-export" rule work for you? (using it in my NLP project where it works nicely, using TS 2.5)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if my code is problematic or if this warning can safely be ignored, if it is safe to ignore then what's the best way of suppressing it

No. You might get a runtime `undefined`.

## Quick Fix

Merge the three files into one. They are already tightly coupled.